# Word meaning "to walk clumsily among many obstacles"?

Tags: single-word-requests

Example:

> I kept [...] among the ocean of trees.

I thought of *striding* but I think it doesn't imply that there are obstacles. What's a better choice?

Comment: "stumbling along"?

Comment: 'Striding' implies a rapid pace and large steps — rather the opposite of what would probably be possible in a heavily wooded landscape.

Comment: '_prep_ the ocean of trees' does not sit well with synonyms of 'stagger'. And 'among the ocean of trees' does not work. '... through the ocean of undergrowth' might.

Comment: "Stride" doesn't imply clumsiness in any way.

Comment: You obviously haven't listened to Fergie's song Clumsy http://www.metrolyrics.com/clumsy-lyrics-fergie.html

Answer (score 26, accepted):

> Stop **bumbling** about the room, knocking things all over the place.

[bum·ble](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/bungle)
v. bum·bled, bum·bling, bum·bles
v.intr.

1. To speak in a faltering manner.
2. To move, act, or proceed clumsily. See Synonyms at blunder.

v.tr.
To bungle; botch.
[Perhaps blend of bungle and stumble.]
bumbler n.
*The American Heritage® Dictionary of the English Language, Fourth Edition copyright ©2000 by Houghton Mifflin Company. Updated in 2009. Published by Houghton Mifflin Company. All rights reserved.*

Answer (score 23):

Perhaps [*blunder*](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/blunder) would fit the bill; particularly the first verb meaning:-

> To move clumsily or blindly. [American Heritage Dictionary via the Free Dictionary].

Answer (score 10):

[Drag](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/drag): (from M-W)

> - to move with slowness or difficulty.

[Stumble](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/stumble):

> - to walk unsteadily or clumsily

also the expression:

[push through (something)](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/push+through) : (From TFD)

> - to work through or force one's way through something.
> - I pushed through the snow, trying to get to the post office on time. The snow was very deep, but I pushed through.

Comment: I would say "dragging" implies pulling a heavy object along the ground behind you - to move *something* with slowness or difficulty.  I'm not sure about "pushing through" either, unless the trees are so close they need pushing out of the way. "Stumbling" is a pretty good fit though.

Comment: I gave different options that might fit the context given. Drag does not necessarily mean that you are pulling a weight but it may imply  that your are moving with  difficulty because of tiredness or other impediments. Same as push through, the idea is of moving in a difficult environment where you also have to clear the way to pass through. ( The image of a ocean of trees is quite challenging)

Comment: @mwfearnley - Here, 'drag' is being used *intransitively*. (I don't think it's the right word here either, but my objection is based on the fact that when you *drag*, it's usually because you are tired, bored or otherwise unmotivated, not because you're encountering external obstacles.)

Comment: @ErikKowal - yes as you said tiredness or motivation may be some of the reasons for dragging that why I think that it may be an option to be considered by OP.

Comment: I don't often hear "drag" being used intransitively, but yes, I accept that it can be.  I don't see any hint of tiredness in the original question though - the problem isn't with me, but the trees.  I think dragging implies an inherent difficulty of movement, not external obstacles.

Answer (score 9):

You could **grope your way through** steep or obstacle-infested terrain if you were physically having to steady yourself by grabbing hold of objects like the trunks of saplings, rock outcrops, foliage and so on.

You could **pick your way through** terrain where the footing was slippery, uneven, overgrown, prone to sinkholes or quicksand etc., obscured from view by low-growing plants, or impeded by broken-down barbed-wire fences, nettles, spiny branches or other problematic vegetation.

Comment: Yeah, "grope" is especially good if your visibility is obscured, eg, by darkness or thick vegetation.

Comment: "pick your way through" to me implies someone is moving slowly, but carefully (i.e. not clumsily). Perhaps my impression is in opposition to the definition though.

Comment: @MichaelMior - Fair point. That being said, any missteps by someone who is making their way carefully over difficult terrain might easily give the impression of clumsiness.

Comment: @ErikKowal Agreed. Although I think picking your way through doesn't imply that those missteps occur.

Answer (score 3):

I quite like 'stagger', the word implying not only the gait, but also the way the obstacles may be staggered accross the path.

Comment: I think "staggering" more implies someone who is faint or wounded, and hence unsteady on his/her feet (even in normal terrain).

Answer (score 3):

The two words that come to my mind have both been said already - stumble, and blunder. Both mean to move clumsily, and both imply obstacles. I thought it might be helpful to explore the differences between them.

When you stumble, you lose your footing (perhaps because of an obstacle, perhaps because your legs are poorly coordinated. I would definitely stumble through an unlit room full of furniture on a dark night. You can't stumble quickly, or with force. It's definitely a hesitant kind of movement- though you might have been moving quickly before you stumbled.

When you blunder, it's because you have come up (probably with some force) against a large object which impedes your progress. Blundering can also be metaphorical, and in this case, it means that you made a massive mistake in some argument or social interaction.

Answer (score 2):

*Lumbering* amongst the trees, of course.

This emphasizes density of the trees.  You might choose a different word to attribute an additional drive to the actor,  e.g. *blunder* would imply a mistake, *barge* a lack of care.

Main Entry: lumber
Part of Speech: verb
Definition: walk heavily, clumsily
Synonyms: barge, clump, galumph, lump, plod, shamble, shuffle, slog, stump, trudge, trundle, waddle
Antonyms: glide
http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/lumber

Comment: This is a brilliant answer, although the OP's "ocean" of trees might call for more of a swimming metaphor, like "treading". Personally I'd lose "ocean" as it isn't right for trees and it doesn't conjure obstacles. I'd use something like plowing through the trees.

Comment: Paul Bunyan, lumbering amongst the trees with his axe and his ox. Together they clear-cut and hauled 100 acres a day. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paul_Bunyan

Comment: "Lumbering", to me, means walking with a loose-legged plodding style, where the legs seem to wave about as they move.  Usually done by a tall person with long legs.  Doesn't strongly imply bumbling/blundering along.

Comment: @HotLicks Yep. Clumsy might not be equatable with the fault implicit in bumbling unless dexterity with trees is to be expected. In this case perhaps the obstacles are at fault in which case the cognate of lumber which could be lame might apply. The vernacular is more likely to assign blame. Prose more likely not.

Comment: Lumbering means moving in a way caused by one's mass or a problem with one's gait. It's a word for when internal obstacles cause clumsy walking. It's not fitting when the obstacles are external.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie I'd be interested to know if lumbering is in fact only due to internal obstacles or why grammatically the word cannot refer to an external obstacle effecting an internal state. I used the conservative word because clumsy was not directly associated with trees so it would be natural to assume the internal state were only tangentially related, then extended the state. @ punstress since you would not be clumsy in an ocean as you would in trees I figured it was an imagination of a dizzying amount of trees and that random trunks on the floor getting in the way were in opposition

Comment: @tommj The answer quotes a thesaurus with an incomplete definition; it's clearer if you check that thesaurus' associated dictionary entry: "[lumber²](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/lumber): to move clumsily or heavily, **especially from great or ponderous bulk**" (emphasis mine). I suppose external obstacles could count, if they were carried and bulky, yes, but not external impeding terrain.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie with respect to the feel of the word in all its definitions I suppose I was thinking of the person's tiredness as directly related to being clumsy and the obstacles as 'among' those reasons. In that case the bulk would be from the increased density of deoxygenated blood. You're right it would be clearer to say why but we don't know this.

Comment: @tommj Deoxygenated blood… Well that took an odd turn. But a point of physics: if deoxygenated blood is denser, that would make it have less volume for the same mass; i.e., *less* bulky.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie Less viscous, constricted and therefore denser. Similarly with lactic acid build up in the muscle which is therefore harder to move imparting a feeling of bulk. My assumption is there is a conscious and odd oceanic experience occurring. Yours appears to be that this person just happens to actually be in an ocean of trees responding normally. If it were a literal ocean of saplings rather than a visual imagination of a forest your version could seem more correct.

Comment: Occam's Razor says they're just being poetic. If that is an important point that your answer relies on though, you might consider asking the asker to clarify the ambiguity.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie ok sounds like good advice

Answer (score 1):

**slog** or **plod**

http://www.thefreedictionary.com/slog
http://www.thefreedictionary.com/plod

> To walk or progress with a slow heavy pace; **plod**: **slog** across the swamp; **slogged** through both volumes.
>
> To make (one's way) with a slow heavy pace against resistance.

Answer (score 0):

A **Carom** is defined as "to strike and rebound". It's a pool term, but it can be applied to other things as well, so in this case it would be "I kept *caroming* among the ocean of trees."

Although, if it were me and you did use my answer, I would change "among" for "through", I think it just sounds better.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use **plodded** or **traipsed**, though the latter has a slightly flippant connotation to me.

Answer (score 0):

'Clamber' is a word that comes to mind.

Comment: I think clamber implies a sense of urgency of movement. This may or may not be what the OP was looking for, but I associate clamber with franticness.

Comment: You're thinking of 'clamour', which is something else. Clamber: intransitive verb   : to move (as up, around, through, or under something) by or as if by catching hold with the hands and feet : CRAWL, STRUGGLE, CLIMB *clamber into a tank* *clamber out of an overcoat* *clamber to emotional heights* *construction workers clambered down from their scaffolding— Robert Shaplen*
transitive verb   : to scramble up : CLIMB *hodmen, clambering a ladder— Washington Irving

Comment: No, I'm thinking of clamber. I understand the definition. I'm simply suggesting what the use of the word implies to me.

Comment: The word does not imply franticness in my understanding or in the dictionary definitions. This is not unusual. All of us have idiolects, that is, personal understandings of words that are not necessarily the same as those of others.http://triggs.djvu.org/century-dictionary.com/djvu2jpgframes.php?volno=02&page=144&query=clamber

Comment: Please expand your answer with rationale and examples.

Comment: Matt: Look in a good dictionary.

Answer (score -2):

> I kept **waddling** among the ocean of trees.

[wad·dle](https://www.google.com/search?q=define%3Awaddle)

1. walk with short steps and a clumsy swaying motion

**Waddle** also seems to work pretty well with the *ocean* imagery in your sample sentence.

Comment: I would say that "waddle" basically means "to walk like a duck".  It doesn't capture a sense of trying to avoid objects.